# Ruby metaprogramming: How can make module method see class's variable

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

For example I have a module and a class:

```
module SimpleModule
  def self.class_hello
    puts "hello from #{@@name}"
  end
end

class SimpleClass
  @@name = 'StackOverFlow'
  def self.test
    SimpleModule.class_hello
  end
end
```

Then I test by calling module method from class:

```
SimpleClass.test
```

I meet exception:

> uninitialized class variable @@name in SimpleModule (NameError)

I know here because scope of module is not same as class scope. So my question is: How can I share SimpleClass scope for SimpleModule scope?

I put metaprogramming because here is just simple example, after that I will advanced by calling dynamic module from dynamic class. (that is the reason why I don't want to use some keyword such as **include** or **extend**)

**@Edit**
In fact I want to implement Ruby extends on my own. Here is my already developed version:

```
# implementation
class Class
  def custom_extend(module_name)
    module_name.methods(false).each do |method|
      define_singleton_method(method) do |*args, &block|
        module_name.send(method, *args, &block)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And here is my custom module and class for testing:

```
# -------------------------------------------------------------
# Demonstration
module SimpleModule
  def self.class_hello_world
    puts 'i am a simple module boss'
  end

  def self.class_hello_name
    puts "hello from #{@@name}"
  end
end

class SimpleClass
  custom_extend  SimpleModule
  @@name = 'StackOverFlow'
end
```

Here is my two test:

```
SimpleClass.class_hello_world  # work
SimpleClass.class_hello_name   # not work
```

Comment: Why not add the class to the module?

Comment: @user000001 as I said, this is a simplified code. the real thing is I implement again ruby-liked **include** and **extend** keyword. Because of this, I need to import all functions programmatically from module to class. I can do this now. The only thing I cannot now is sharing scope between two.

Answer (score 6):

## Updated answer

Here's a slightly modified version of your code. No `include`, `extend`, `append_features` or `module_function` are needed. It wouldn't be hard to add `custom_include` with the same structure.

UPDATE: Make sure to read @7stud's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42045992/6419007), with a similar structure and very good explanation.

```
class Class
  def custom_extend(module_name)
    module_name.instance_methods(false).each do |method|
      define_singleton_method(method) do |*args, &block|
        module_name.instance_method(method).bind(self).call(*args, &block)
      end
    end
  end
end

module SimpleModule
  def class_hello
    puts "hello from #{@name}"
  end
end

class SimpleClass
  @name = 'class'
  custom_extend SimpleModule

  def self.test
    class_hello
  end
end

SimpleClass.test
#=> hello from class
```

---

## Original answer

## Usual way

The usual way would be :

```
module SimpleModule
  def class_hello
    puts "hello from #{@name}"
  end
end

class SimpleClass
  @name = 'StackOverFlow'
  extend SimpleModule

  def self.test
    class_hello
  end
end

SimpleClass.class_hello
```

but you don't want it. (why?)

## Your way

In your code, `SimpleClass` and `SimpleModule` are totally independent from one another. It's clear that you get a `NameError`. You need to somehow pass the `name` information.

#### As name parameter :

```
module SimpleModule
  def self.class_hello(name='')
    puts "hello from #{name}"
  end
end

class SimpleClass
  @@name = 'StackOverFlow'
  def self.test
    SimpleModule.class_hello(@@name)
  end
end
```

#### With klass parameter :

```
module SimpleModule
  def self.class_hello(calling_class=self)
    calling_class.class_eval{
      puts "hello from #{@name}"
    }
  end
end

class SimpleClass
  @name = 'StackOverFlow'
  def self.test
    SimpleModule.class_hello(self)
  end
end

SimpleClass.test
```

#### With `binding` parameter :

```
module SimpleModule
  def self.class_hello(b)
    puts "hello from #{b.eval('@@name')}"
  end
end

class SimpleClass
  @@name = 'StackOverFlow'
  def self.test
    SimpleModule.class_hello(binding)
  end
end

SimpleClass.test
```

#### With `my_ruby_extend SimpleModule`

It surely can be done with a custom `my_ruby_extend`. You'd need to show the desired syntax though, and what you already implemented.

This way, you could tell Ruby that `SimpleClass` and `SimpleModule` are linked. When a method or a variable isn't found in `SimpleModule`, it could be sought in `SimpleClass`.

Comment: thanks for nice answer. My purpose is trying to re-implementing **extend** keyword, that why I don't want to use: 1. extends keyword (obvious). 2. add parameters to module. (because the implementation of module doesn't need to know who should really call this).

Comment: thanks. I just try to re-implement **extend** as an exercise. I want to test if anything in Ruby can be done by using its core language (such as attr_accessor, alias ...) can be implemented by using Ruby metaprogramming. So maybe as you said, **extend** and **include** in Ruby is a part of Ruby core language and must be done at C++ layer.

Comment: `C`, not `C++` ;). I'd say that you can implement `my_extend` with plain Ruby. You need to define it and use it somehow, in order to tell Ruby that `SimpleClass` has been "my_extended" with `SimpleModule`. This information was missing from your question. BTW, it sounds that Rubinius would interest you.

Comment: thanks. I have edited my question for including what have I done. Please take a look. thanks.

Comment: thanks so much :D nice answer. I could I can 1000 upvotes for both of you ^^^

Answer (score 4):

> I just try to re-implement extend as an exercise.

ruby's `extend()` doesn't work like this:

```
module SimpleModule
  def self.class_hello_world
    puts 'i am a simple module boss'
  end

  def self.class_hello_name
    puts "hello from #{@@name}"
  end
end

class SimpleClass
  custom_extend  SimpleModule
```

For example, the following doesn't work:

```
module Dog
  def self.greet
    puts "hello"
  end
end

class Cat
  extend Dog
end

Cat.greet

--output:--
`<main>': undefined method `greet' for Cat:Class (NoMethodError)
```

`extend()` works like this:

```
module Dog
  def greet
    puts "hello"
  end
end

class Cat
  extend Dog
end

Cat.greet

--output:--
hello
```

In other words, `extend()` inserts the module instance methods--not the module methods(e.g. method names preceded by `self`)--into Cat's singleton class (which is where Cat's class methods live).  In ruby, `include()` and `extend()` have nothing to do with module methods (again, method names preceded by `self`).  Modules have two uses in ruby:

1. As a namespace, e.g. containing `def self.method_name`
2. As a mixin, e.g. containing `def some_method`

include() and extend() deal with #2.

The following solution doesn't work with `@@variables`, but trying to figure out all the twist and turns that `@@variables` exhibit in ruby is not worth the effort--just don't use them.  Use *class instance variables* instead, i.e `@variables` specified outside of any def's:

```
def my_extend(some_module)
  singleton_class.include some_module
end

module Dog
  def greet
    puts @greeting
  end

  private
  def sayhi
    puts "hi"
  end
end

class Cat
  @greeting = "hello"
  my_extend Dog
end

Cat.greet
#Cat.sayhi  #=>`<main>': private method `sayhi' called for Cat:Class (NoMethodError) 

Cat.class_eval {sayhi}  #Change self to the Cat class so the implicit
                        #self variable that calls sayhi is equal to Cat

--output:--
hello
hi
```

Now, you just need to implement `my_include` and substitute it inplace for `include`. :)

Here's a shot at `my_include()`:

```
class Class

  def my_include(module_)
    #For public and protected methods:
    module_.instance_methods(include_super=false).each do |meth_name|
      meth = module_.instance_method(meth_name)
      define_method(meth_name) do 
        meth.bind(self).call
      end
    end

    #For private methods:
    module_.private_instance_methods(include_super=false).each do |meth_name|
      meth = module_.instance_method(meth_name)
      define_method(meth_name) do
        meth.bind(self).call
      end
      private :"#{meth_name}"
    end

  end
end

module Dog
  def greet
    puts "hello"
  end

  def go
    puts "run, run run"
  end

  private
  def sayhi
    puts "hi"
  end

end

class Cat
  my_include Dog
end

c = Cat.new
c.greet
c.go
c.sayhi 

--output:--
hello
run, run run
 #=>`<main>': private method `sayhi' called for #<Cat:0x007fc014136f60> (NoMethodError)
```

With `my_extend()`:

```
class Class

  def my_include(module_)
    #For public and protected methods:
    module_.instance_methods(include_super=false).each do |meth_name|
      meth = module_.instance_method(meth_name)
      define_method(meth_name) do 
        meth.bind(self).call
      end
    end

    #For private methods:
    module_.private_instance_methods(include_super=false).each do |meth_name|
      meth = module_.instance_method(meth_name)
      define_method(meth_name) do
        meth.bind(self).call
      end
      private :"#{meth_name}"
    end

  end

  def my_extend(module_)
    singleton_class.my_include module_
  end

end


module Dog
  def greet
    puts @greeting
  end

  private
  def sayhi
    puts "hi"
  end
end

class Cat
  @greeting = "hello"
  my_extend Dog
end

Cat.greet
#Cat.sayhi  #=>private method `sayhi' called for Cat:Class (NoMethodError)
Cat.class_eval {sayhi}

--output:--
hello
hi
```

Comment: Nice code and good explanation. We came up with a very similar solution at almost the same time. I wasn't happy with `module_name` or `modul`, `module_` is a good compromise. I didn't consider private methods, and your methods don't accept arguments or blocks ;)

Comment: @EricDuminil, *your methods don't accept arguments or blocks*--Child's play!  Too much of a pain to type out when hacking.  *We came up with a very similar solution at almost the same time*--I posted my solution an hour ago.  Then I went to work on the private methods, which were a little trickier, and I added them to my example.

Comment: I didn't mean to say it's an insurmountable problem. Just that it could be added.

Comment: Wow. so great :D thanks both of you so much. The nicest part here is `meth.bind(self).call`. I don't know this before, so I am headache for thinking how to share scope from class to module. I have asked a similar question here: [custom include ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42036886/ruby-metaprogramming-cannot-send-a-method-to-a-module). That people here said that we can't not implemented **custom-include** on my own :D (because I cannot call a module instance method directly).

Comment: **Note** I have seen again. I don't know why original author have removed some comments. But because of that, it makes me give up on implement **custom-include** and jump to **custom-extend** :D

Comment: @TrầnKimDự, *The nicest part here is meth.bind(self).call. I don't know this before*--Neither did I.  It's just the path I was led down.  The first breakthrough was discovering `instance_method()` in class Module.  Then after several failures trying `bind()`, I was able to create the proper context to get ruby to assign the right value to self to make bind() work.  *I don't know why original author have removed some comments.*--I'm the original author, but I didn't remove any comments.  *But because of that, it makes me give up on implement custom-include*--custom-include is in my answer.

Comment: @7stud wow. short line of code with amazing background insight :D 
I don't say about your post but my question from link in my comment: in that topic, Cary Swoveland said that he cannot implement **include** using only-ruby :D (now he deleted that comment). Your answer is fully understandable for **custom extend** and **custom-include**. thanks.

Comment: @TrầnKimDự,  *Cary said...*--Ah, I see. Here's some more background: `instance_method()` returns an UnboundMethod, but the UnboundMethod docs say that you have to bind to an instance of a subclass of a module.  No subclass involved here, so I concluded that bind wouldn't work.  Later, having run out of ideas,  I thought I would try bind() anyway, but I didn't get the error specified in the docs: *'bind': bind argument must be an instance of B`*.   So, I kept playing around with bind fully expecting to get that error once I got rid of the error I was getting.  Never happened. :)

Comment: Wow. nice work. looks like if we put `self` Ruby won't throw exception. Because someone on StackOverFlow meet same error as you said. In this link:  [Is it possible to force bind to instances of other classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13234284/ruby-unbound-methods-is-it-possible-to-force-bind-to-instances-of-other-classes) So maybe there is some "magical thing" here.

Comment: Very good answer. I modified my answer to implement a custom `extend` (subsequently purged). Not only did I do it the same way you did, but it even involved a "cat" and a "dog". The only explanation I can think of is that we had a subconscious mindlink. Anyway, I obviously think that approach is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

**Simplify question**

You can simply your question by modifying your code as follows.

```
module SimpleModule
  def self.class_hello
    puts "hello from #{@@name}"
  end
end

class SimpleClass
  @@name = 'StackOverFlow'
end

SimpleModule.class_hello
  # NameError: uninitialized class variable @@name in SimpleModule
```

**Which class?**

Clearly, the module's module method `class_hello` must be informed of the class whose class variable `&&name` is desired. We therefore must give that class as an argument of `class_hello`. We then use [Module#class_variable_get](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Module.html#method-i-class_variable_get
) to extract the class variable's value.

```
module SimpleModule
  def self.class_hello(klass)
    puts "hello from #{ klass.class_variable_get(:@@name) }"
  end
end

SimpleModule.class_hello(SimpleClass)
  # hello from StackOverFlow
```